# While getting ArrayList from Hashmap using Iterartor the output is not as expected

Tags: java

I have created an jsp page that takes the id from user and in turn calls the servlet in which I am reading the value entered by the user and then passing to my method and that method returns the object and I am storing in a Hashmap as key value pair.

```
String id = request.getParameter("ManagerId");
    //response.getWriter().println(id);
    services1 s=new services1();
    try {
        //s.getList(id);
        String name="";
        String[] nameArray=new String[10];
        System.out.println("id is ===> "+id);
        Map<Object, Object> map=messageservice.getReportees(id);
        Set s1=map.keySet();
        for (Iterator iterator = s1.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
        {
             name = (String) iterator.next();
             Collection c=map.values();
                String value="";
                for (Iterator iterator1 = c.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
                {
                    value = (String) iterator1.next(); //error in this line        
                    Map<Object, Object> mapData=jiraservice.getJiras(value);
                    //System.out.println(value);


                    System.out.println("returning map");
                    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
                    out.println("<html><body><table>\r\n" + 
                            "<tr>\r\n" + 
                            "<th>User Id</th>\r\n" + 
                            "<th>Username</th>\r\n" + 
                            "</tr>\r\n" + 
                            "<tr>\r\n" + 
                            "<td>"+value+"</td>\r\n" + 
                            "<td>"+name+"</td>\r\n" + 
                            "</tr>\r\n" + 
                            "</table></body></html>");
                   }
            }
         }
```

Here is the output:

```
      User Id   Username
      AR12345   Anagha R
      User Id   Username
      MS12345   Anagha R
      User Id   Username
      at12345   Anagha R
      User Id   Username
      AR12345   Madhusudan S
      User Id   Username
      MS12345   Madhusudan S
      User Id   Username
      at12345   Madhusudan S
      User Id   Username
      AR12345   Amreen Taj
      User Id   Username
      MS12345   Amreen Taj
      User Id   Username
      at12345   Amreen Taj
```

In my output it should print only

```
      User Id   Username
      AR12345   Amreen Taj
      User Id   Username
      MS12345   Madhusudhan
      User Id   Username
      at12345   Anagha R
```

I am not getting to know how should this be done.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback(s). And welcome to upvote level, which gives you even more ways to show appreciation ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating over all the values of the `Map` for each key of the `Map`, which means if the `Map` has 3 key-value pairs (as it seems from your output), you are printing each of them 3 times.

You only need a single loop:

```
Map<Object, Object> map=messageservice.getReportees(id);
Set<Map.Entry<Object,Object> s1=map.entrySet();
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Object,Object> iterator = s1.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)  {
    Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry = iterator.next();
    Object name = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
    ...
}
```